Batched Stored functions with parameter using npgsql in C#
I would like to know if it is possible to execute a store function using NpgsqlBatch having NpgsqlBatchCommand with parameter?
I am using Npgsql 8.0.4
Basically, it tried the following:
sql = $"SELECT {FunctionName}($1, $2)";
foreach (var value in values)
{

    var cmd = new NpgsqlBatchCommand(sql)
    {
        Parameters =
        {
            new NpgsqlParameter {NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.someType, Value = value.Item1},
            new NpgsqlParameter {NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.someType2, Value = value.Item2)},
        }
    };
    batch.BatchCommands.Add(cmd);
}

batch.Prepare();
var reader = batch.ExecuteReader();

but the reader is empty.
I made it worked for function inserting but not on function selecting
Any ideas?

Yes, this is supposed to work - please post a fully runnable minimal code sample that reproduces the problem.

I found out another thread on which you explain a function should not return refcursor. I bet the issue is coming from that :)

Yes, probably - and this shows why it is important to always post the full information when posting question; there's no way of knowing in your above post that the function returns a refcursor.

You are right. Your last comment also show how it is important to stay indulgent with posters. There are a lot of different profiles in here, beginners who might not always recognize important information, employees following strict company policies and especially kind helpers who take on their time to provide benevolent answers.
